# Where is the Mono develop User Interface?

Tags: ide, mono

I have downloaded and Installed MONO_DEVELOP on my mac using this linke - http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Only the command line version of mono gets installed. How should I get the IDE working? I have been trying it for two days now. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonoDevelop and Mono are not the same thing.

You can download MonoDevelop from http://monodevelop.com/.

Comment: If you click on the the link you provided, it would ultimately take you to the same page link that I have given.

Comment: @TusharMathur: No; it doesn't.  http://monodevelop.com/Download, then http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Mac/XamarinStudio-4.0.8.dmg

Comment: Xamarin Studio is the IDE? Im so embarrassed about posting the question :(